# How to open textfile and write to it append-style with php?

Tags: php, text-files

How do you open a textfile and write to it with php appendstyle

```
    textFile.txt

        //caught these variables
        $var1 = $_POST['string1'];
        $var2 = $_POST['string2'];
        $var3 = $_POST['string3'];

    $handle = fopen("textFile.txt", "w");
    fwrite = ("%s %s %s\n", $var1, $var2, $var3, handle);//not the way to append to textfile
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To append data to a file you would need to open the file in the append mode (see [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen)):

> - **'a'**
>     Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
> - **'a+'**
>     Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

So to open the *textFile.txt* in *write only append* mode:

```
fopen("textFile.txt", "a")
```

But you can also use the simpler function [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) that combines `fopen`, `fwrite` and `fclose` in one function:

```
$data = sprintf("%s %s %s\n", $var1, $var2, $var3);
file_put_contents('textFile.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: +1 for going into detail.  `fprintf()` would also be a good choice.