# Export API response to CSV

Tags: php, csv, codeigniter

I need to export my API response into CSV file. For now, I can export it and the output seems to loop (there are 8 items with status delivered in my API response). When I check my CSV file, contains 5 rows with similar output which only the last data where status is delivered. Where is my mistakes, can anyone help? :/

CSV for API request:

```
 - Tracking #,Order #,Unique ID
 - AB74832493,0dajKDhsa,478324
 - CD78437294,kDHIdsan98,768542
```

API response:

```
Array
(
    [status] => delivered
    [last_trace] => 2020-04-21 13:10:00 : Shipment Delivered
    [last_action_date_time] => 2020-04-21 13:10:12
)

Array
(
    [status] => delivered
    [last_trace] => 2020-02-29 12:55:00 : Shipment Delivered
    [last_action_date_time] => 2020-02-29 12:55:51
)
```

Controller:

```
public function getstatusbyid()
    {

    $csv_file = file('C:\wamp64\www\testing\application\csv\packet.csv');
    $csv_data = [];
    foreach ($csv_file as $line) {
        $csv_data[] = str_getcsv($line);
    }

    $order_no = json_encode(array_column($csv_data, '0'));
    $tracking = json_encode(array_column($csv_data, '1'));
    $unique_id = array_column($csv_data, '2');
    $access_key = 'SOMETHING';

    foreach ($unique_id as $i => $id) {
        $url = "https://track.my/api/getstatus/$id";

        $data = array(
            'unique_id'       => $id,
            'access_key'      => $access_key
        );

        $data_string = json_encode($data);

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        $resultinfo = json_decode($result, true);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($resultinfo);

        $status = $resultinfo["status"];
        $date = $resultinfo["last_action_date_time"];

        $resultdata = array();
        if ($status == 'delivered') {
            foreach ($resultinfo as $item) {

                $resultdata[] = array(
                    'status'    => $status,
                    'date'      => $date
                );
            }


            $fp = fopen('C:\wamp64\www\testing\application\csv\track.csv', 'w');

            foreach ($resultdata as $fields) {
                fputcsv($fp, $fields);
            }

            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're repeatedly re-opening (and recreating) the CSV file. You can either change 'w' to 'a' to [append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448887/how-to-open-textfile-and-write-to-it-append-style-with-php), or even better: move the calls to `fopen()` and `fclose()` to outside `foreach ($unique_id as $i => $id) {` so you're not repeatedly reopening the file every time.

While you're at it, you should also check for `fopen()` failure.

```
public function getstatusbyid()
    {

    $csv_file = file('C:\wamp64\www\testing\application\csv\packet.csv');
    $csv_data = [];
    foreach ($csv_file as $line) {
        $csv_data[] = str_getcsv($line);
    }

    $order_no = json_encode(array_column($csv_data, '0'));
    $tracking = json_encode(array_column($csv_data, '1'));
    $unique_id = array_column($csv_data, '2');
    $access_key = 'SOMETHING';

    if ( FALSE === ( $fp = fopen('C:\wamp64\www\testing\application\csv\track.csv', 'w') ) ) {
        die( "Error opening CSV file." ); // TO DO: handle this better
    }

    foreach ($unique_id as $i => $id) {
        $url = "https://track.my/api/getstatus/$id";

        $data = array(
            'unique_id'       => $id,
            'access_key'      => $access_key
        );

        $data_string = json_encode($data);

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        $resultinfo = json_decode($result, true);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($resultinfo);

        $status = $resultinfo["status"];
        $date = $resultinfo["last_action_date_time"];

        $resultdata = array();
        if ($status == 'delivered') {
            foreach ($resultinfo as $item) {

                $resultdata[] = array(
                    'status'    => $status,
                    'date'      => $date
                );
            }

            foreach ($resultdata as $fields) {
                fputcsv($fp, $fields);
            }

        }
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Why do I get this error ya? "fclose(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource"

Comment: Sorry, I put the call to `fclose()` on the wrong line. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now i get all the data correctly, but recreate for many times. Why does it create for 5 times ya? Even with my previous code.

delivered,"2020-04-21 13:10:12"
delivered,"2020-04-21 13:10:12"
delivered,"2020-04-21 13:10:12"
delivered,"2020-04-21 13:10:12"
delivered,"2020-04-21 13:10:12"
delivered,"2020-02-29 12:55:51"
delivered,"2020-02-29 12:55:51"
delivered,"2020-02-29 12:55:51"
delivered,"2020-02-29 12:55:51"
delivered,"2020-02-29 12:55:51"

Comment: I've put the content of packet.csv on the question, the label CSV for API request. In the file got 15 rows of data without the header.

Comment: Hey, already fixed that! I just realised i loop based on the column in my CSV, in this example is 3 but on my real CSV file got 5. That's why it loops for 5 times. Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: By the way, do you know how can I capture my Tracking  # and Order # from packet.csv into track.csv? :/

Comment: Please show exactly where you want the tracking # and order # to appear in the output.

Comment: Post the question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/61673096/13359447