# Capture data from CSV file contain variable for API request to save in new CSV file

Tags: arrays, csv, codeigniter

I need the tracking number and order number when every line of Unique ID send the API request to the URL, and capture it to save in the new CSV file altogether with the API response.I really need help for this :/

packet.csv (CSV file contains variable for API request)

```
- Tracking #,Order #,Unique ID
- AB74832493,0dajKDhsa,478324
- CD78437294,kDHIdsan98,768542
```

track.csv (API response)

```
delivered,"2020-04-21 13:10:12"
delivered,"2020-02-29 12:55:51"
delivered,"2020-04-21 12:42:16"
```

desired track.csv (API response) :

```
Tracking #,Order#,Status,Date  ((get the tracking and order from packet.csv)
0CS7lPuyKzO6,YT2010421266182766,delivered,"2020-04-21 13:10:12"
327231739327,YT7328729173217832,delivered,"2020-02-29 12:55:51"
743287493274,YT7438749327489324,delivered,"2020-04-21 12:42:16"
```

Controller :

```
public function getstatusbyid()
    {

        $csv_file = file('C:\wamp64\www\tetsing\application\csv\packet.csv');
        $csv_data = [];
        foreach ($csv_file as $line) {
            $csv_data[] = str_getcsv($line);
        }

        $order_no = json_encode(array_column($csv_data, '0'));
        $tracking = json_encode(array_column($csv_data, '1'));
        $unique_id = array_column($csv_data, '2');
        $access_key = 'SOMETHING';

        if (FALSE === ($fp = fopen('C:\wamp64\www\testing\application\csv\track.csv', 'w'))) {
            die("Error opening CSV file."); // TO DO: handle this better
        }

        foreach ($unique_id as $i => $id) {
            $url = "https://track.my/api/getstatusbyid/$id";

            $data = array(
                'unique_id'       => $id,
                'access_key'      => $access_key
            );

            $data_string = json_encode($data);

            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

            $result = curl_exec($curl);

            curl_close($curl);

            $resultinfo = json_decode($result, true);
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($resultinfo);

            $status = $resultinfo["status"];
            $date = $resultinfo["last_action_date_time"];

            $resultdata = array();

            $resultdata[] = array(
                'status'    => $status,
                'date'      => $date
            );

            if ($status == 'delivered') {
                foreach ($resultdata as $fields) {
                    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this updated code, with comments to describe what's happening. Basically, you need to loop through each line in `packet.csv`, make the appropriate cURL call, and output the results:

```
public function getstatusbyid()
    {
        $access_key = 'SOMETHING';
        $url = "https://track.my/api/getstatusbyid/$id";

        if (FALSE === ($fp = fopen('C:\wamp64\www\testing\application\csv\track.csv', 'w'))) {
            die("Error opening CSV file."); // TO DO: handle this better
        }

        $csv_file = file('C:\wamp64\www\tetsing\application\csv\packet.csv');

        // Loop through each line in packet.csv:
        foreach ($csv_file as $line) {
            $csv_data = str_getcsv($line); // Get the next line

            list( $order_no, $tracking, $id ) = $csv_data; // Split it up

            $data = array(
                'unique_id'       => $id,
                'access_key'      => $access_key
            );

            $data_string = json_encode($data);

            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

            $result = curl_exec($curl);

            curl_close($curl);

            $resultinfo = json_decode($result, true);
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($resultinfo);

            $status = $resultinfo["status"];
            $date = $resultinfo["last_action_date_time"];

            // Create the array of data to output:
            $resultdata = array(
                'tracking'  => $tracking,
                'order'     => $order_no,
                'status'    => $status,
                'date'      => $date
            );

            if ($status == 'delivered') {
                fputcsv($fp, $resultdata);
            }

        }

        fclose($fp);
    }
```

Comment: I have 4K+ data in my CSV file, and I need to request API to each line but need to send 50 line max without crashing the system and save the data into CSV file. Can use the same way?

Comment: I don't understand. The way my code works, it sends one request at a time, which is well below the 50 line max. Are you saying you want to send 50 requests at a time, not just one? If so, what would the request look like?

Comment: Sorry, I was blank that time. Anyway, your answer helps me alot! Appreciate it so much! T-T